# Petición ajax con evento toggleSelect excede parámetros

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un problema entre manos en el trabajo que necesito solucionar con urgencia, a ver si alguien puede arrojar algo de luz porque no consigo encontrar nada en internet...

Tenemos una tabla primefaces que muestra registros paginados en 1000 por página, dicha tabla dispone de un checkbox con el evento ajax toggleSelect asociado, el problema viene en que cuando se pulsa dicho checkbox, según puedo ver en las herramientas del desarrollador, se están enviando 1012 parámetros en la petición ajax.

El servidor wildfly de produccion está configurado en un máximo de 1000 parámetros por petición y no tenemos autorización para subirlo, sin embargo, el requisito funcional es que se puedan seleccionar 1000 registros de la tabla a la vez.

Me preguntaba si había alguna forma de poder limitar o definir los parámetros que se envían en la petición para que solo sean los 1000 que corresponden a los registros de la tabla.

**Esto es la parte inicial del payload de la petición ajax, las primeras líneas serían parámetros que no corresponden a los registros seleccionados:**

```
javax.faces.partial.ajax: true 
javax.faces.source: componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459:listadoObjetos 
javax.faces.partial.execute: componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459 componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:listadoDataTable 
javax.faces.behavior.event: toggleSelect 
javax.faces.partial.event: toggleSelect 
componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459:listadoObjetos_checked: true 
componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459: componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459 
componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459:listadoObjetos_rppDD: 1000 
componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459:listadoObjetos_checkbox: on 
componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459:listadoObjetos_checkbox: on 
componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459:listadoObjetos_checkbox: on 
componentelistadoObjetosPagina:formularioPagina:base:componenteLista:j_idt2459:listadoObjetos_checkbox: on
-- más datos --
```

**Y esto es la parte inicial de la tabla con los eventos ajax asociados:**

```
  <p:fragment id="listadoDataTable"> 
  
  <h:form>
  <p:dataTable id="listadoObjetos" var="objetoDTO"
   widgetVar="listadoObjetos"
   rowSelectMode="checkbox"
   paginator="true" rows="20"
   rowsPerPageTemplate="20,200,960,1000"
   binding="#{dataTableObjetos}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.listado}"
   rendered="#{cc.attrs.bean.mostrarTabla}"
   selection="#{cc.attrs.bean.objetosSeleccionados}"
   rowKey="#{objetoDTO.id}" lazy="true"
   sortOrder="DESCENDING"
   sortBy="#{objetoDTO.id}">
    
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" process="@form" partialSubmit="true"/> 
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.onUnselectRowListener}" process="@form" partialSubmit="true"/> 
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.toggleSelectListener}" process="@form" partialSubmit="true"/> 
    <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.pageEventListener}" />

   <p:column selectionMode="multiple" toggleable="false" id="mult"
    rendered="#{cc.attrs.bean.columnaCheckbox}">
   </p:column>

   <!-- A partir de aquí columnas de la tabla -->
´´´

Muchas gracias de antemano
```